# SSRS Format Matrix Header Column as "hh:mm tt" not working as expected

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Matrix with the Hour of Day (an INTEGER columns with values between 6 to 17). However, I'd like to display these values in "hh:mm tt" format while maintaining the sort order of the raw integer values.

I've set the tool tip to see the value that I'm using in the Format expression, which looks correct (`1/1/2023 6:00:00 AM`), but then the formatted column header is putting the hour value in the hour and minutes position (`6:06 AM`).

What could be causing this?

Properties:

[image: properties]

How it displays (the lower value in red rectangle is the tooltip):

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two fields there and the format should **not** have a field reference in it.

As `CStr(Fields!Hour12.Value)` appears to give you the correct value then you should set as follows:

1. `Value` property = `CStr(Fields!Hour12.Value)`
2. `Format` property to `"hh:mm tt"`

The `Format` just sets what format string you want to apply to the `Value`. In your example you were taking the result of the formatted `Hour12` field and using that as the format string.

Comment: That didn't work. For some reason the Format property was not being applied and it was just displaying the entire datetime of `Fields!Hour12.Value`. In the end, I set the `Value` property to the formatted value using: `=Format(Fields!Hour12.Value, "hh:mm tt")` and left the `Format` property blank.

Comment: @crichavin - because the value was converted to a string with CSTR, the format wasn't recognized as a date/time. The Value should just be the field and the format property `hh:mm tt`.

Comment: OK, It wasn't clear what datatypes you had hence the guess at the value.

Comment: @HannoverFist you are correct. When I changed the value to just `Fields.Hour12.Value`, then set the `Format` to `hh:mm tt` it also worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, given the value of `Fields.Hour12.Value` was a datetime from the database eg. `1/1/2023 6:00:00 AM`, I set the `Value` property of the column text to `=Format(Fields!Hour12.Value, "hh:mm tt")` and left the `Format` property blank.

[image: properties]